# SQL Oracle conditional group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, conditional-statements

I am struggling with the following problem, any help would be appreciated!
I need to take the summation of a variable but the level of the group by dependents on a condition (see 3.), this goes beyond my knowledge of SQL.

So my query should:

1. Take the summation of AMOUNT per ID and SPLIT (see f.e. ID_1, 100 + 50)
2. With CUST having the value of the most recent DATE (on a ID, SPLIT level) (see f.e. ID_1, A and B -> A)
3. If CUST has the same DATE value (on a ID, SPLIT level) it should keep both values, and there should also be a split per CUST in AMOUNT (see f.e. ID_3, 30 and 10 + 10)

My fictional dataset looks like this (script to recreate see bottom):

| ID | SPLIT | CUST | DATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | SPLIT_YES | A | 05/01/2024 | 100 |
| ID_1 | SPLIT_NO | A | 04/01/2024 | 200 |
| ID_1 | SPLIT_YES | B | 03/01/2024 | 50 |
| ID_2 | SPLIT_YES | A | 05/01/2024 | 50 |
| ID_2 | SPLIT_NO | A | 04/01/2024 | 300 |
| ID_2 | SPLIT_NO | B | 03/01/2024 | 300 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_YES | B | 04/01/2024 | 90 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_NO | B | 04/01/2024 | 30 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_NO | A | 04/01/2024 | 10 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_NO | A | 03/01/2024 | 10 |

And the final result of the query should be this:

| ID | SPLIT | CUST | DATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | SPLIT_YES | A | 05/01/2024 | 150 |
| ID_1 | SPLIT_NO | A | 04/01/2024 | 200 |
| ID_2 | SPLIT_YES | A | 05/01/2024 | 50 |
| ID_2 | SPLIT_NO | A | 04/01/2024 | 600 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_YES | B | 04/01/2024 | 90 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_NO | B | 04/01/2024 | 30 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_NO | A | 04/01/2024 | 20 |

Thank you all!

I tried using a lot of different with statements to do it step by step, with no correct result. Using a with statement I am able to solve step 1 and 2 combined by first taking the summation per ID and SPLIT and then join based with the most recent CUST VALUE, but this join is my issue since it makes step 3 impossible.

```sql
WITH LatestDatePerID AS (
    SELECT ID, 
    "SPLIT",
           MAX(DATE_COLUMN) AS MAX_DATE
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY ID, "SPLIT"
),
LatestCustPerID AS (
    SELECT t.ID, 
           t.CUST, 
           t."SPLIT",
           t.DATE_COLUMN, 
           t.AMOUNT
    FROM your_table_name t
    JOIN LatestDatePerID l ON t.ID = l.ID AND t.DATE_COLUMN = l.MAX_DATE and t."SPLIT" = l."SPLIT"
)
SELECT ID, 
       CUST,
       "SPLIT",
       DATE_COLUMN, 
       SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
FROM LatestCustPerID
GROUP BY ID, "SPLIT", CUST, DATE_COLUMN
ORDER BY ID, DATE_COLUMN DESC;
```

So it is not taking the summation of the other neglected rows.
I am breaking my head over this.

Script to recreate table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test_Table_MM (
    ID VARCHAR2(10),
    SPLIT VARCHAR2(10),
    CUST VARCHAR2(10),
    DATE_COLUMN DATE,
    AMOUNT NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_1', 'SPLIT_YES', 'A', TO_DATE('05/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 100);
INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_1', 'SPLIT_NO', 'A', TO_DATE('04/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 200);
INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_1', 'SPLIT_YES', 'B', TO_DATE('03/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 50);
INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_2', 'SPLIT_YES', 'A', TO_DATE('05/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 50);
INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_2', 'SPLIT_NO', 'A', TO_DATE('04/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 300);
INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_2', 'SPLIT_NO', 'B', TO_DATE('03/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 300);
INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_3', 'SPLIT_YES', 'B', TO_DATE('04/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 90);
INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_3', 'SPLIT_NO', 'B', TO_DATE('04/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 30);
INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_3', 'SPLIT_NO', 'A', TO_DATE('04/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 10);
INSERT INTO Test_Table_MM (ID, SPLIT, CUST, DATE_COLUMN, AMOUNT) VALUES ('ID_3', 'SPLIT_NO', 'A', TO_DATE('03/01/2024', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 10);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as text we can copy/paste and execute, **NOT** images); a detailed explanation of the problem; and the expected output (again, as text, not images). You need to explain why the output data looks like it does because if you `GROUP BY id, split` then for `id_1/SPLIT_NO` the `cust` is `A`, not `B` and the date does not match either.

Comment: Apologies, not super familiar with posting. I added the script to recreate the sample data, in which I also corrected the mistake of A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT id, 
       split,
       cust,
       date_column,
       CASE num_cust
       WHEN 1
       THEN total_amount
       ELSE total_cust_amount
       END AS amount
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE rnk WHEN 1 THEN cust END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY id, split) AS num_cust
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id, split ORDER BY date_column DESC) AS rnk,
           SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id, split) AS total_amount,
           SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id, split, cust) AS total_cust_amount
    FROM   test_table_mm t
  ) t
  WHERE  rnk = 1
)
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | SPLIT | CUST | DATE_COLUMN | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | SPLIT_NO | A | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 200 |
| ID_1 | SPLIT_YES | A | 2024-05-01 00:00:00 | 150 |
| ID_2 | SPLIT_NO | A | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 600 |
| ID_2 | SPLIT_YES | A | 2024-05-01 00:00:00 | 50 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_NO | A | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_NO | B | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 30 |
| ID_3 | SPLIT_YES | B | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 90 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eY1F9MOK)